# Transform array of generic objects into an array of another generic class

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm looking for a way to convert an array of one generic type to another. Here's my use case:

I have a base library with the following Composite:

```
// leaf
public interface Job<T extends JobResult> {
  public T doJob();
}

public class CompositeJob<T extends JobResult> implements Job<T>{
  private Job<T>[] jobs;
  // ...
}

// component
public interface Worker<T extends JobResult> {
  public T doWork();
  public Job<T>[] getJobs();
  public void addJob(Job<T> job);
}

public class HardWorker<T extends JobResult> implements Worker<T> {
  public T doWork() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I also have a custom library that imports the base library, which uses a more domain-specific name for a Job, a "Customer". I'd like users of my custom library to only interface through my Customer types, so I can change the implementation of the base library without disturbing my public API.

I'm hindered because `Worker.getJobs()` returns an array of `Job[]`. I'd like to write a method that can convert `Job[]` to `WorkItem[]` to prevent exposure of the base library's types, but I'm not sure how to write that conversation method in Java.

Here's the signature of the method I want:

```
public WorkItem<T1>[] convert(Job<T>[] jobs) {
  for (Job<T> job : jobs) {
    // convert a T to a T1
    // create a new WorkItem using the Job as input
  }
}
```

Comment: We don't know anything about `WorkItem`.

Comment: I know how to create a new `WorkItem` from the properties of a `Job`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to write a method that can convert `Job[]` to `WorkItem[]` to prevent exposure of the base library's types.

[Adapter Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) might help you in this case specially read *Object Adapter pattern* section.

Read more [Adapter Pattern - GOF](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Adapter.aspx)

> The adapter pattern is a design pattern that is used to allow two incompatible types to communicate. Where one class relies upon a specific interface that is not implemented by another class, the adapter acts as a translator between the two types.

[image]

Comment: I had been trying to use an approach of casting, but maybe an Adapter is the way to go. Let me go try this.